# How to avoid pod restarts in unchanged statefulsets on chart version update

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Suppose there are more than one statefulsets in the same chart.

Suppose, each commit updates the chart version, even if there are changes in only 1 of the statefulset spec (either spec, or config map)

When we deploy this new version, is there a way to filter and rollout only those statefulsets which actually have changes? Currently, due to chart version upgrade, all of the statefulset go through a rollout.

Comment: Helm normally does this on its own.  Do you have some detail of the chart that changes on every upgrade (maybe a pod label containing the Helm release number)?  Do you have an [mcve] that demonstrates a StatefulSet that gets redeployed when it doesn't need to be?

Comment: You can configure Statefulsets to follow different [Update Strategies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#update-strategies). You can use `OnDelete` if you want to trigger restarts manually

Comment: @HiroCereal - but that would mean manually deleting many many pods..

Comment: @DavidMaze I reckon there's a checksum kind of thing that updates..

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.